# How to sort JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, sorting, redux

Can anyone help me with the sorting of json data in ReactJs please? Right now it is not working properly for me. Also if i want to sort as per the title, would it be same? Thanks.

I am trying as below:

```
componentDidMount() 
{
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                data.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.userId> b.userId;
                })
                data.sort();
                this.setState({data: data});

            });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br/><br/>
                <br/><br/>

                < table className="table">

                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <tbody>{this.state.data.map(function (item, key) {
                        return (
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td>{item.userId}</td>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.title}</td>
                                <td>{item.body}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )

                    })}</tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: The second invocation to `data.sort()` (without custom sort function logic) is overwriting the initial sort logic which is why your custom logic of comparing `a.userID > b.userId` is not achieving any expected results.  @gaiazov Answer below `a.title - b.title` answers the sort-by-title question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `compareFunction` in `data.sort` needs to return an integer, according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). When comparing numbers, you can simply subtract `a` number from `b` number, in your case, `a.userId - b.userId`.

This code works

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        data.sort((a, b) => a.userId - b.userId);
        this.setState({data: data});

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

@mshrivas, please test the following code for sorting by title :

```
componentDidMount()
{
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
      this.setState({data: data});
    });

}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <br/><br/>
      <br/><br/>

      < table className="table">

        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <tbody>{this.state.data.map(function (item, key) {
          return (
            <tr key={key}>
              <td>{item.userId}</td>
              <td>{item.id}</td>
              <td>{item.title}</td>
              <td>{item.body}</td>
            </tr>
          )

        })}</tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Source for localeCompare: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/764/how-to-sort-alphabetically-an-array-of-objects-by-key-in-javascript. This worked for me.